# How to call custom keyword into testcase level in katalon studio?

Tags: katalon-studio, katalon

I am trying to call custom keyword into testcase level in katalon studio:

[image]

But I am not able to do it as shown in this GIF.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your GIF, we're assuming that you're in Script view. Can you try using the `CustomKeywords.` class to insert your custom keyword instead? Please see our docs for more information:

1. [Using Custom Keywords in the Script View](https://docs.katalon.com/docs/author/keywords/custom-keywords/introduction-to-custom-keywords-in-katalon-studio#use-custom-keywords-in-the-script-view)
2. [How to use a custom keyword from other custom keywords and step definition classes in Katalon Studio](https://docs.katalon.com/docs/author/keywords/custom-keywords/how-to-use-a-custom-keyword-from-other-custom-keywords-and-step-definition-classes-in-katalon-studio)

You can also check out this tutorial about Custom Keywords and Call Methods in Studio: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2zc2x1BcRMo